# After apply lestsencrypt , my nginx server is dead

Tags: django, ssl, nginx, uwsgi, lets-encrypt

I deployed django project, with nginx, uwsgi.
but after apply ssl(letsencrypt), it works and my server is getting slowly and finally have no react.
Is it related with applying ssl??

Please comment even if it is little hint.
I totally panic now...

Comment: You could provide your nginx file in here

Comment: You really should provide more information, like your nginx config file, logs, etc...

Comment: Even putty dosent work at all... so i cannot confirm nginx.conf